# Display large amount text on mouseover

Tags: asp.net, html, css, tooltip, mouseover

I'm using this pop-up tooltip:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/showhint.htm

so that whenever I mouse-over a [?] sign, a message appears.

In the script provided:

```
<a href="#" class="hintanchor" onMouseover="showhint('Please choose a username. Should consist of alphanumeric characters only.', this, event, '150px')">[?]</a>
```

I am meant to enter the text to display in pop-up within the `showhint` function as shown above.

My problem is that I have a large amount of text to display (i.e. half a page of Word document size) and they need to be arranged with breaks between paragraphs.

When I put the chunk of texts within the first parameter of showhint function, it doesn't work.

How do I get the tooltip to display my long message with the appropriate breaks etc?

Thanks!

Comment: thanks for all the help below. i've decided to create a new page with these text and open the page instead onclick of the [?]

Answer (score 1):

The "Show Hint" script you are using seems to be accepting HTML tags like  inside - so that you can put your text in a paragraph

```
<a href="#" class="hintanchor" onMouseover="showhint('<p>Please choose a username.</p><p>Should consist of alphanumeric characters only.</p>', this, event, '150px')">[?]</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add html tags in showhint text itself as shown below. It works.

```
<a href="#" class="hintanchor" onmouseover="showhint('<b>Please choose a username.</b> &lt;p&gt;Should consist of alphanumeric characters only.&lt;/p&gt;', this, event, '150px')">[?]</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting \n or \n\r or <br> or <br/> in where you want your breaks?
That's helped me out in the past

Answer (score 1):

Normally that is not, what hover-help is for. Maybe you better use showhint to display a teaser and a link to open something like a sidebar where you can display normal html and which stays displayed while the user does his input.

Documentation says *HTML is supported*, so did you try text like:

```
<html>line-1<br/>line-2</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try to use < br > for line breaks? (without spaces)

like that:

```
<a href="#" class="hintanchor" onMouseover="showhint('Please choose a username. <br> Should consist of alphanumeric characters only.', this, event, '150px')">[?]</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your popup css use word-wrap property as mention below

```
     <div id='row' style='word-wrap:break-word;'>
```

it will wrap the text accordingly

```
    #hintbox{ 
     /*CSS for pop up hint box */ 
    position:absolute; top: 0; 
    background-color:lightyellow; width: 150px;
    /*Default width of hint.*/ 
    padding: 3px; border:1px solid black;  
    font:normal 11px Verdana; 
    line-height:18px; 
    z-index:100; 
    border-right: 
    3px solid black; 
    border-bottom: 
    3px solid black; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    Word-wrap:break-word;
```

}